# I want to go to top of page with <a href> using angular JS $anchorscroll

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to execute $anchorscroll with href like this

Html:

```
</div>
<div>
<a class="button"  ng-click="scrollTo('section')" ng-href="#{{url}}" title="{{section}}">Next</a>
</div>
</body>
```

js:

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    $location.hash(id);
    console.log($location.hash());
    $anchorScroll();
};
```

Here it move to top of the page. Not to the section id.

can u pls help me with this.

Comment: Do you have an element with id as 'section'?

Comment: code is correct, +1 to @Wayne

Answer (score 0):

You need an element on the page with the id `section`.
Just like this: `<section id="section"></section>`. It must have the id attribute with the value `section`

And check if you have included the `$anchorScroll` dependency to your controller/link function.

Visit the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) for examples.

Comment: I already done. what u r saying..u just saying the thing from documentation. Pls tell me what i am dng wrong.